# Perl HTTP Tiny response

Tags: json, perl, http

How to put the JSON response of `HTTP::Tiny` in Perl?

```
use HTTP::Tiny;

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get('http://example.com/');

die "Failed!\n" unless $response->{success};

print "$response->{status} $response->{reason}\n";

while (my ($k, $v) = each %{$response->{headers}}) {
   for (ref $v eq 'ARRAY' ? @$v : $v) {
        print "$k: $_\n";
   }
}

print $response->{content} if length $response->{content};
```

How to put the `$response->{content}` into variable to be passed into html(tt2)?

Comment: You mean `my $cont = $response->{content};` ?

Comment: and how to pass it into list/array?

Comment: I think you want to read https://perlmaven.com/json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass your content to the TT processor like this:

```
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process('some_template.tt', { content => $response->{content} })
  or die $tt->error;
```

Perhaps you want to store it in an intermediate scalar first:

```
my $content = $response->{content};

$tt->process('some_template.tt', { content => $content })
  or die $tt->error;
```

Perhaps you want to build up TT's variable hash before passing it to the processor.

```
my %vars;

$vars{content} = $response->{content};

$tt->process('some_template.tt', \%vars)
  or die $tt->error;
```

Or you could use a hash reference instead of an actual hash:

```
my $vars;

$vars->{content} = $response->{content};

$tt->process('some_template.tt', $vars)
  or die $tt->error;
```

**Update:** In a comment, [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque) suggests that you might actually be asking how to decode JSON content into an array or a hash. And I agree that's another way to interpret your question.

You'd need to use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module. And it would look something like this:

```
use JSON;

my $json_parser = JSON->new; # Perhaps other options here, see docs.

my $decoded_json = $json_parser->decode($response->{content});
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the JSON module? I _think_ that's all they actually need.

Comment: Possibly. It really wasn't clear what they were trying to do. I'll add some information. Thanks.

Comment: There was a follow-up, so this seems to have been useful to them. :)

Comment: I would not recommend the JSON module; it slows down both modules it wraps, and doesn't use the best options. If you are restricted to core modules, you're stuck with JSON::PP; otherwise, I would recommend Cpanel::JSON::XS, or JSON::MaybeXS and Mojo::JSON which both use it by default if installed.